# How do ulimit(UL_GDESLIM, 0) and select work?

Tags: c, unix

We are migrating our C application from Solaris 8 to Solaris 10. I am getting error when I run this code on Solaris 10. I am using the 32 bit gcc compiler.

```
nFDs = ulimit(UL_GDESLIM, 0);
n=select(nFDs, &set, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Error:

```
Error : GetKey_(): select(): Invalid argument
```

I got why I got this error, because `nFDs` is more than 1024.
Below is from the `select.h`

```
#ifdef  _LP64 
#define  FD_SETSIZE      65536 
#else 
#define  FD_SETSIZE      1024
```

Could you please give me pointer how the `ulimit(UL_GDESLIM, 0)` and `select` works and which header I need to fix ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this by the way? :O Just curious because I haven't actually tried this on Solaris 10 before, only on other distros of Unix.

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle's documentation, it appears like there's a "hard limit" to the max file descriptors that Solaris follows. This can be changed, however, by adding the following line to `/etc/system` and rebooting:

```
set rlim_fd_max = 65536
```

The line above will set the hard limit to 65536. Once this hard limit has been set, you can *then* change the "running" value of this property with the `ulimit` kernel function call or as you've shown from within a C application with system calls to `ulimit(...)` and `select(...)`.

Source:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19644-01/817-5051/pt_tuningos.html#wp57451